# Time Index of Lévy Process

Tags: stochastic-processes

Consider (for all $t\geq 0$) a linear time transformation function $\nu(t)=at+b$ with the following properties:

1. $\nu(0)=-1$
2. $\nu(t)$ is an increasing function of the time index $t$ i.e. $a>0$.
3. $\nu(t)$ is a continuous function of the time index $t$.
4. $\nu(t)$ is a 1-1 function of time index $t$.
5. $\nu(t+1)$-$\nu(t)=a$ for all $t\geq 0$.

**Q**: Can we define a Lévy process with $\nu(t)$ as the time index (rather than $t$) or do we need more conditions on $\nu(t)$? In other words, I would like to see the possibility of defining $\{Z_{\nu(t)};t\geq 0\}$, where $Z_{\nu(t)}$ is a Lévy process.

Comment: It is a little unclear what you are trying to do.  First, what do you mean that the *index* $t$ "is a continuous function"?  What is it a function of?  Second, although transforming the index creates a new process, it usually is not a Lévy process, because it differentially changes the durations. Are you asking what functions $T$ will transform one Lévy process into another?

Comment: I editted the question to make it more clear.

Comment: The original $Z_{t}$ was a Levy process itself?

Comment: @ Cristián Antuña : no, $Z_t$ is not necessarily a Levy process. If this is the case, then I know that $Z_{\nu(t)}$ will be an additive process and not necessarily a Levy process as said in Example 14.5 [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=bVlieV8GBrIC&pg=PA469&dq=Time+changed+levy+process&hl=en&sa=X&ei=a4T3VJCHNa7PsQSh3IKACA&ved=0CE8Q6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=Time%20changed%20levy%20process&f=false). Normally, when we want to define a Levy process, we consider a time index $t\geq 0$. I just wanted to know the  possibility of defining $Z_{\nu(t)}$.

Comment: What are the requirements on $Z_t$?